# Reading an XML file using Jquery, how to combine this with Server Sent Events and keep the page up-to-date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, server-sent-events

I have the following XML file (data.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user>
      <id>2011</id>
      <posX>12</posX>
      <posY>29</posY>
      <title>Senior Developer</title>
  </user>
  <user>
      <id>2022</id>
      <posX>99</posX>
      <posY>99</posY>
      <title>updated!</title>
  </user>
</users>
```

I read this file using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'js/data.xml', // name of file you want to parse
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: parse,
                    error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
                  });
```

and display it using;

```
function parse(document){
                  $(document).find("user").each(function(){ 
                    $("#test").append(  // this is where all the reading and writing will happen
                    '<div style="position: absolute; top: '+$(this).find('posY').text()+'px; left: '+$(this).find('posX').text()+'px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">ID: '+$(this).find('id').text()+ // which represents user->id
                    '<br /> X: '+$(this).find('posX').text()+
                    '<br /> Y: '+$(this).find('posY').text()+
                    '<br /> Title: '+$(this).find('title').text()+
                    '</div>'
                    );
                  });
                }
```

This all works fine. The XML is read and the data is displayed. Now this only happens when you load the page, so 1 time only.

It is possible for users to update the xml (let's say the title is changed), but you only see these changes if you refresh the page. I know you can load the the xmlfile each x seconds using jquery, but I've also read that server send events can push the xml file when changes are made in it.

I would like to do just that. The problem is: how do I implement SSE to achieve this?

I did some research and found some demo code:

```
var source = new EventSource("js/data.xml");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

but this didn't work.

So what I want:

1. Load page + load XML (this is what is currently does)
2. if the XML is changed in anyway, push the xml to the page (using SSE)
3. display the data (so if posX is changed, the div should be moved aswell)

My current working HTML code minus the SSE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <style>
       #test { position: relative; width: 500px; height: 500px; padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                function parse(document){
                  $(document).find("user").each(function(){ 
                    $("#test").append(  // this is where all the reading and writing will happen
                    '<div style="position: absolute; top: '+$(this).find('posY').text()+'px; left: '+$(this).find('posX').text()+'px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">ID: '+$(this).find('id').text()+ // which represents user->id
                    '<br /> X: '+$(this).find('posX').text()+
                    '<br /> Y: '+$(this).find('posY').text()+
                    '<br /> Title: '+$(this).find('title').text()+
                    '</div>'
                    );
                  });
                }

                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'js/data.xml', // name of file you want to parse
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: parse,
                    error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
                  });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help me out

Comment: As far as I can tell you cannot do this with a static file. The server must send specific data to the client to trigger the event. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events   My best advice whould be to set up a timeout and perform a `HEAD` request and check to see if the Last Modified date has changes on the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

> As far as I can tell you cannot do this with a static file. The server
>   must send specific data to the client to trigger the event. see:
>   developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/… My best advice
>   whould be to set up a timeout and perform a HEAD request and check to
>   see if the Last Modified date has changes on the XML file.

**Similar question:**

[$.ajax() call, only on updation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870566/ajax-call-only-on-updation)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  ifModified: true,
  url: 'js/data.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse
});
```

This will only call success if the XML file has been updated since the last request.

Comment: Uhm bummer, can't I use SSE than to trigger jquery to read the file again? Your suggestion (while good) kinda takes away the SSE idea

Comment: Yeah sure you can use SSE to monitor the file on your server then tell the client when it has updated. But you have to consider a few things - mainly complexity, browser support. IE doesn't support SSE at all - but if IE isn't an issue for you then that's fine. In regards to complexity, because the server will tell the client there has been a change and then the client will request the change, that is a lot of overhead. The best way would be to have the server send the updated data when it is changed and not ajax it from the client side.

Comment: IE is no problem, they will support it eventually (I hope) "The best way would be to have the server send the updated data when it is changed and not ajax it from the client side" sounds like a solution, but how to do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this can be accomplished. Here's how:
1. PHP page with while Loop
    while (1) {  //Continuous Loop
          Logic here to check a DB or XML file and see if its changed since 
           last check. IF it's changed output XML. Use this function fr_EncodeXML to 
           remove all line breaks and excess spaces which are problematic.

```
function fr_EncodeXML($sData){
        $sData = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $sData); // Remove line breaks etc
        $sData = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', $sData); // Remove excess spaces etc
        $sData  = htmlentities($sData );   // Make valid UTF-8. 
        return $sData;
    }


$xml_string  =  fr_EncodeXML($xml_string);
      echo "data:" . $xml_string . "\n\n";

      ob_end_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(100);   //Time determines refresh rate

 }
```

2. J Script page.
   The J script will receive the data in the eventsrc.onmessage = function(event) {..event.data object
   The XML text has its '<' &  '>' escaped. Use this JS function to restore it to XML that can be parsed to DOM.

```
function fr_htmlDecode( sXML ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a'); a.innerHTML = sXML;
    return a.textContent;
};
```

Hope this helps.